# Unable to render special characters

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly

In our application we have created a maven project and we are deploying that on Wildfly 8 server. The problem is some of the Danish characters (special characters) are not getting rendered properly when we are deploying the application in our Dev server, but it is Ok when we are deploying in the server on our local machine.

Can anyone suggest what can go wrong here or what can cause the issue. I think we need to change the server encoding but the I have also not changed the encoding of our local server. So wondering what the issue is.

Comment: Sounds more like it's a character set issue on the machine itself. Have you tried ensuring that you have the Danish language pack installed and/or a UTF-8 compatible font pack?

Comment: No, will check that surely.

Comment: Thanks, it is solved. Indeed we had to change the file encoding on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Dev server is running on windows then, do the following :

a)      Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

b)      Locate the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESYSTEMCurrentControlSetServicesEapHostConfiguration

c)       Click Edit, click New, and then click DWord Value.

d)      Type IdentityEncodingFormat, and then press ENTER.

e)      Click Edit, click Modify, type the value 0x1, and then click OK.

f)       Exit the Registry Editor.